# PHP Array to XML with no numbers

Tags: php, xml

PHP array to XML problem. I have an array and when trying to convert it into an xml file, it is counting the total fields using "item0" "item1"...so on. I only want it to display "item" "item". Examples below. Thank you.

PHP code turning the array($store) into an XML file.

```
// initializing or creating array
$student_info = array($store);

// creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_student_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><student_info></student_info>");

// function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($student_info,$xml_student_info);

//saving generated xml file
$xml_student_info->asXML('xmltest.xml');


// function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml($student_info, &$xml_student_info) {
    foreach($student_info as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
            else{
                $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("item$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
        }
        else {
            $xml_student_info->addChild("$key","$value");
        }
    }
}
```

What the XML file looks like (with the item# error)

```
<student_info>
<item0>
    <item0>
        <bus_id>2436</bus_id>
        <user1>25</user1>
        <status>2</status>
    </item0>
    <item1>
        <bus_id>2438</bus_id>
        <user1>1</user1>
        <status>2</status>
    </item1>
    <item2>
        <bus_id>2435</bus_id>
        <user1>1</user1>
        <status>2</status>
    </item2>
</item0>
</student_info>
```

Once again, I just want each "item" to display "item" with no number. and the first and last "item0"... I dont know what thats about. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer to question

Replace this:

```
else{
    $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("item$key");
    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
}
```

with this:

```
else{
    $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("item");
    array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
}
```

## Answer to comment

I don't know how your array is structured but, from the output, I would guess the problem is in the following line:

```
$student_info = array($store);
```

So, change to this:

```
if (!is_array($store)) {
    $student_info = array($store);
} else {
    $student_info = $store;
}
```

This should fix it